# How to generate variable from string JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I would like to know about generating variable based on array.

```
var arr = new Array('1','2','3');
var message = new Array('a','b','c');

for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
var $["message"+i] = message[i];
}

//I would like to create
var message1
var message2
var message3
```

Anyone can help me please? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript#5187652

Comment: what is the purpose of this code? maybe there's another easier way to go about it.

Comment: Ehhhh it's sorta possible, you can do `window["message"+i]`

Comment: You can use `eval` but it's not suggested...